# How to get the size or frame of a nib/xib without instantiating it?

Tags: ios, size, frame, xib, nib

Right now we are instantiating the nib, getting its frame, and then destroying it.

Is it possible to get the nib's frame without instantiating it?  If so, how?

Comment: Why do you need to do that in the first place?